# Create a stacked bar chart with 3 traces for 2 bars

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to replicate the following stacked bar chart with `plotly`. I attach one screenshot for every hover text I get when hovering on a bar. As you will see there are 2 issues. First I cannot achieve 3 colors, besides the fact that I create them in the `legend` and secondly I cannot put `First dose` as top bar besides the fact that I use `factor()` based on the levels. Maybe there is an issue with the way I have created my dataset. I have no problem if you have to reform it instead of fix the `plotly` code to replicate the chart.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
library(plotly)
Category<-c("First dose","Full vaccination")
`Uptake first dose`<-c(19.8,7.6)
`Uptake full vaccination`<-c(0,0)
`Not vaccinated`<-c(80.2,92.4)
ch5<-data.frame(Category,`Uptake first dose`,`Uptake full vaccination`,`Not vaccinated`)
ch5$Category <- factor(ch5$Category, levels = ch5[["Category"]])

ax <- list(
  title = "",
  showticklabels = FALSE,
  showgrid = FALSE
)
fig <- plot_ly(ch5, y = ~Category, x = ~`Uptake first dose`,
               type = 'bar', name = 'Uptake first dose',marker = list(color = 'lightgreen'))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~`Uptake full vaccination`, name = 'Uptake full vaccination',marker = list(color = 'green'))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~`Not vaccinated`, name = 'Not vaccinated',marker = list(color = 'gray'))
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = ax,xaxis=list(title="",showgrid=F), barmode = 'stack')

fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a problem with your dataset. The 7.6% of full vaccination is listed under first doese. Therefore your coloring might not work.

Furthermore I transformed the data into a long format for an easy way to create hovertemplates.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

# data
Category<-c("First dose","Full vaccination")
`Uptake first dose`<-c(19.8,0)
`Uptake full vaccination`<-c(0,7.6)
`Not vaccinated`<-c(80.2,92.4)
ch5<-data.frame(Category,`Uptake first dose`,`Uptake full vaccination`,`Not vaccinated`)

# transform data
data.long <- ch5 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Category,
               names_to = "vac",
               values_to = "percent") %>%
  mutate(vac = str_replace_all(vac, "\\.", " "),
         vac = fct_rev(factor(vac))) 

# add plot
plot_ly(data.long) %>%
  add_bars(y = ~Category,
           x = ~percent,
           color = ~vac,
           text = ~vac,
           colors = c("darkgreen", "green", "gray"),
           hovertemplate = paste('<b>%{y}</b>',
                                 '<br>%{text}: %{x} ',
                                 '<extra></extra>')) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack",
         yaxis = list(autorange="reversed"),
         hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "black",
                           bordercolor = "black",
                           font = list(color = "white")),
         shapes = list(type = "line",
                       y0 = 0, y1 = 1, yref = "paper",
                       x0 = 70, x1 = 70),
         annotations = list(text = "Target (70.0%)",
                            showarrow = FALSE,
                            x = 70,
                            y = 1.05,
                            yref = "paper"))
```

Comment: as expert u might help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138948/create-a-filled-area-line-plot-with-annotated-scatters-using-plotly

Comment: could this be transformed to relative gauge ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177361/turn-stacked-bar-chart-to-gauge-chart-in-plotly