# Add new traces in plotly line chart based on shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have this dataframe which contains the `Value` of each `Country` per `VaccinationWeek` and the cumulative Value (`EU`) for every week.

```
VaccinationWeek Country Value
1          2020w1      EU     3
2          2020w1     CHE     2
3          2020w1     ITA     1
4          2020w2      EU     5
5          2020w2     CHE     3
6          2020w2     ITA     2
```

and I have created a shiny app in which when the user have selected (default) no Countries from `pickerInput()` then only the EU line will be displayed in the line chart like:

[image]

For every country then that the user selects (normally more than 2) in the line described above will be added the respective line for this country and the hover text will include data for both EU and the selected Country in all lines like:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)

VaccinationWeek<-c("2020w1","2020w1","2020w1","2020w2","2020w2","2020w2")
Country<-c("EU","CHE","ITA","EU","CHE","ITA")
Value<-c(3,2,1,5,3,2)
dat<-data.frame(VaccinationWeek,Country,Value)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "p1",
        label = "",
        choices = c("CHE","ITA"),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = c("CHE","ITA"),
        options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("line")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$line<-renderPlotly({
    dat <- subset(dat, Country %in% input$p1)
    
    plot_ly(dat,
            x = ~VaccinationWeek, 
            y = ~Value,
            text = ~Value) %>%
      add_trace(
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers+text',
        fill = 'tozeroy',
        fillcolor = 'lightgreen',
        marker = list(color = 'green'),
        line = list(color = 'green'),
        textposition = "top center",
        hovertemplate = paste0("<b>%{x}</b>
                           Value: %{y} 
                          <extra></extra>"),
        hoveron = 'points') 
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea with just lines (see your second image).

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)

VaccinationWeek<-c("2020w1","2020w1","2020w1","2020w2","2020w2","2020w2")
Country<-c("EU","CHE","ITA","EU","CHE","ITA")
Value<-c(3,2,1,5,3,2)
dat<-data.frame(VaccinationWeek,Country,Value)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "p1",
        label = "",
        choices = c("CHE","ITA"),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = c("CHE","ITA"),
        options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("line")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$line<-renderPlotly({
    
    dat <- subset(dat, Country %in% c("EU",input$p1))

    plot_ly(dat,
            x = ~VaccinationWeek, 
            y = ~Value,
            text = ~Value,
            color = ~Country,
            customdata = dat$Country) %>%
      add_trace(
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        hovertemplate = paste("Country: %{customdata}",
                              "Uptake first dose (%): %{y}", 
                              "<extra></extra>",
                              sep = "\n"),
        hoveron = 'points') %>%
      add_text(    
        textposition = "top center",
        showlegend = F,
        hoverinfo = "skip") %>% 
      layout(hovermode = "x unified",
             hoverlabel = "none",
             legend = list(itemclick = F, itemdoubleclick = F))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Or a line plot with filled area and single lines for each country (your first image with added lines).

```
# Just the plot, needs to be copied into the shiny app 
    plot_ly(x = ~VaccinationWeek, 
            y = ~Value,
            text = ~Value,
            color = ~Country) %>%
      add_trace(
        data = subset(dat, Country == "EU"),
        customdata = subset(dat, Country == "EU")$Country,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        fill = 'tozeroy',
        fillcolor = 'lightgreen',
        marker = list(color = 'green'),
        line = list(color = 'green'),
        hovertemplate = paste("Country: %{customdata}",
                              "Uptake first dose (%): %{y}", 
                              "<extra></extra>",
                              sep = "\n"),
        hoveron = 'points') %>%
      add_text(        
        data = subset(dat, Country == "EU"),
        textposition = "top center",
        showlegend = F,
        hoverinfo = "skip") %>%
      add_trace(
        data = subset(dat, Country != "EU"),
        customdata = subset(dat, Country != "EU")$Country,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        hovertemplate = paste("Country: %{customdata}",
                              "Uptake first dose (%): %{y}", 
                              "<extra></extra>",
                              sep = "\n"),
        hoveron = 'points')  %>% 
      add_text(        
        data = subset(dat, Country != "EU"),
        textposition = "top center",
        showlegend = F,
        hoverinfo = "skip") %>%
      layout(hovermode = "x unified",
             hoverlabel = "none",
             legend = list(itemclick = F, itemdoubleclick = F))
```

[image]

Comment: I like both your solutions I ll check what fits best thank you

Comment: from the 2nd solution how could I remove the "lightgreen" word from the legend?

Comment: You can overwrite the legend by defining the `name` argument in the first trace.  ```add_trace(data = subset(dat, Country == "EU"),         customdata = subset(dat, Country == "EU")$Country, name = "EU"...```

Comment: In the 2nd method how can you do it to have filled areas for every single line like the green one?

Comment: Adding the `fill` argument in the second `add_trace` may do it. ```add_trace( data = subset(dat, Country != "EU"),  fill = 'tozeroy',  customdata = subset(dat, Country != "EU")$Country, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', hovertemplate = paste("Country: %{customdata}", "Uptake first dose (%): %{y}", "<extra></extra>", sep = "\n"), hoveron = 'points')```

Comment: Im trying to apply the same method here but without result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775199/create-a-plotly-line-chart-with-dynamic-number-of-traces-based-on-shiny-widget-s/70777308#70777308